# No puedo encontrar coordenadas de un número en una matriz (lista de listas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, matrices

Trato de que busque el número 1 en una lista con números repetidos y trato de que me de su ubicación en el mapa, pero sólo busca el numero 0. Y si coloco por ejemplo el 1, no me da la ubicación y no se por qué.

```
def map1(self):#nivel 1
    self.map=[
    [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
    [2,4,2,4,4,4,2,4,2,2],
    [2,4,4,4,0,4,4,1,4,2],
    [2,4,4,2,4,4,4,4,3,2],
    [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
    ]

def boxesposition(self):
    for cy in range(len(self.map)):#busca la posicion en x de la caja
        for cx in range(len(self.map)):#busca la posicion en y de la caja
            if self.map[cy][cx] == 1:
                self.position_cx =cx
                self.position_cy =cy
                print (self.map[cx][cy])
```

Comment: podrías editar tu pregunta añadiendo  como es `self.map`?

Comment: esque es para un juego y el 1 por ejemplo es para caja y el 0 es personaje y trato de buscar la ubicacion de la caja porque el del personaje si me lo da pero si coloco otro numero no lo encuentra

Comment: el self.map es porque es una variable global

Comment: si pero sin importar que lo cambie no me da ninguna ubicacion solo cuando declaro que sea ==0

Comment: si ya vi esos detalles de la posicion en el print pero aun asi no encuentra el 1 solo funciona si pongo el 0 y no se porque

Comment: listo asi esta la matriz pero no encuentra la ubicacion pero si coloco el 0 en lugar del numero 1 si lo encuentra es lo raro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que asumes que la matriz es cuadrada cuando no lo es. El rango de índices del segundo `for` debe ser el número de columnas, es decir, en vez de:

```
for cx in range(len(self.map))
```

debe ser:

```
for cx in range(len(self.map[0]))
```

Al hacer `for cx in range(len(self.map))` te dejas sin recorrer la mitad de la matriz, las últimas 5 columnas, justamente donde está tu 1 perdido...

No obstante, te aconsejo que no uses `range` + indizado y uses `enumerate` para esto, es más legible y considerablemente más eficiente. Dado que asumimos un solo 1 en la matriz, es importante que rompas el ciclo cuando lo encuentres, así te evitas recorrer toda la matriz siempre, aún habiendo encontrado ya el número.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.map=[[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  [2,4,2,4,4,4,2,4,2,2],
                  [2,4,4,4,0,4,4,1,4,2],
                  [2,4,4,2,4,4,4,4,3,2],
                  [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
                  ]

        self.position_cx = None
        self.position_cy = None

    def boxesposition(self):
        for cy, row in enumerate(self.map):
            for cx, n in enumerate(row):
                if n == 1:
                    self.position_cx = cx
                    self.position_cy = cy
                    return

inst = Foo()
print(inst.position_cx, inst.position_cy)
inst.boxesposition()
print(inst.position_cx, inst.position_cy)
```

> ```
> None None
> 7 2
> ```

Solo por curiosidad, un pequeño test de tiempo de ejecución para esa misma lista con los diferentes métodos:

- `range` + indizado sin romper el ciclo:

  > 8.31 µs ± 158 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
- `range` + indizado rompiendo el ciclo:

  > 5.1 µs ± 80.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
- `enumerate` rompiendo el ciclo:

  > 2.4 µs ± 98.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

Comment: muchísimas gracias ya tenia mas de 2 horas sin poder resolverlo